# Is this TypeORM query vulnerable to avoid SQL Injections?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, sql-injection

I am using TypeORM in my project. However, for this specific query, I had to include a raw string. I am aware that using raw strings is a bad idea, however I am unsure what the best way is to work around it and secure it anyway:

```
return this.restaurantRepo.createQueryBuilder()
.insert()
.into(Restaurants)
.values([{
   name: name,
   location: () => `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${latitude} ${longitude})')`,
   user: user,
},
]).execute(); `
```

The line

`location: () => 'ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${latitude} ${longitude})')'`

is where the potential danger lies.
So the question is, is the above query vulnerable, and if so, how should it be secured?

Comment: What is `user`?

Comment: Also what is your table schema `Restaurants`.

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite the query like this:

```
return this.restaurantRepo.createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .into(Restaurants)
  .values([{
    name: name,
    location: () => `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:latitude :longitude)')`,
    user: user,
  }])
  .setParameter('latitude', latitude)
  .setParameter('longitude', longitude)
  .execute();
```

you can refer to [this](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#using-parameters-to-escape-data) for more info.